# Laravel Eloquent get second level of model

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Competition model

[image]

Category model

[image]

Result model

[image]

Controller of competition

[image]

I want to import all of this data from Laravel Eloquent to VueJS but I get error:

> Call to undefined relationship `[competitionResults]` on model `[App\Competition]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, copy your code into your question, dont post images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the calls with `.` like the follwing:

```
Competition::with(
        ['competitionCategories.competitionResults']
      )->get();
```

It simply loads the relationship with its nested relationship: 
the `competitionCategories` with its `competitionResults` relationship.

For more info, please check out this [section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the documentation.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate `competitionCategories`, you can just do `with('competitionCategories.competitionResults')`.